# Russian folk song sung in the movie Russkies?

Tags: перевод

Approximately 30 minutes into the 1987 film "Russkies" the main character, Mischa, sings what I assume to be a Russian folk song. A clip is available on YouTube at [this link](https://youtu.be/CbRhfwSw9z8?t=1901). Can you name that tune or provide a lyrics translation to English that can be googled?

Comment: *Шаланды, полные кефали* ("Scows Full Of Mullet"). https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шаланды,_полные_кефали

Comment: Not a folk song. It's from [Two Soldiers (1943)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_Soldiers_(1943_film)) movie.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cheers to Quassnoi who answered via comment.  The Romanized name of the song is "Shalandy polnye kefali" ("Scows Full of Mullet") by Mark Bernes.  The original is available on YouTube [here](https://youtu.be/hDSxfoHWCS8).  The translated lyrics are available [here](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/shalandy-polnye-kefali-%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-scows-full-mullet.html).